# Android: How to check Service status in Activity's onResume()?

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I'm creating a media player app.

When I starts or resumes the application I want to check if the media player was already playing a song.

So that if it was I will set my Pause/Play `ToggleButton` to **Pause**, else it was not playing earlier then button will set to **Play**.

(i.e. for e.g. if the user was already using the media player and left the app by pressing home or back button & now he resumes the player. then the button should be configured correctly.)

The actual MediaPlayer object is implemented in the `Service` & all the communications are done via `AIDL interface` methods.

I was planning to implement a method:

```
public boolean isMediaPlaying() throws RemoteException {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Problem:** But the `ServiceConnection's onServiceConnected` is executed after on resume.

Please suggest how can I check this status on activity resume?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold reference to yor service in Application class. For example

```
    public class App extends Application {

    private static PlayerService player;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (player == null)
            bindService(new Intent(App.this, PlayerService.class), connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
        player.stop();
        player = null;
        getApplicationContext().unbindService(connection);
    }

    public static PlayerService getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }


    private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            player = ((PlayerService.PlayerServiceListener) service).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            player = null;
        }
    };

}
```

And then in activity onResume use

```
App.getPlayer().isPlaying
```

Comment: I do not understand by `PlayerServiceListener` & by `onTerminate()`

Comment: you shouldn't use onTerminate(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()